# strstr() for a string that is NOT null-terminated

Tags: c, string, indexof, null-terminated

How do I do the **in-place** equivalent of `strstr()` for a *counted* string (i.e. *not* null-terminated) in C?

Comment: You'll have to write your own version.

Comment: Which string isn't null-terminated?  The string being searched, or the sub-string?

Comment: @TimCooper: The one being searched (haystack).

Comment: @SethCarnegie: It's not exactly trivial... I could try KMP or something if I really need to, but I'd rather avoid it if I can.

Comment: You can steal the implementation of `strnstr()` from BSD. But look out for this bug: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/dont-use-strnstr.html

Comment: @mkb: ... Thanks for the link, I'll take a look but that link makes me a bit nervous haha.

Comment: Have you looked at Boyer-moore string searching? It works quite fine without terminating `\0`s and is O(4*n).

Comment: @moshbear: I had heard about it once but I know little about it and I'd totally forgotten it -- I'll look at that, thanks!

Comment: Yes, Boyer-Moore is very good. It's a bit more complicated than KMP, so if you don't find a ready-made implementation, it may not be worthwhile to cook one up yourself. If performance is really important, I would however recommend BM, especially if needles are long. (Best case, BM looks only at every `m`th character.)

Comment: glibc has [memmem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263582/is-there-a-particular-reason-for-memmem-being-a-gnu-extension) (needle and haystack both counted), I'm sure there will be a public domain implementation out there too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're afraid of O(m*n) behaviour - basically, you needn't, such cases don't occur naturally - here's a KMP implementation I had lying around which I've modified to take the length of the haystack. Also a wrapper. If you want to do repeated searches, write your own and reuse the `borders` array.

No guarantees for bug-freeness, but it seems to still work.

```
int *kmp_borders(char *needle, size_t nlen){
    if (!needle) return NULL;
    int i, j, *borders = malloc((nlen+1)*sizeof(*borders));
    if (!borders) return NULL;
    i = 0;
    j = -1;
    borders[i] = j;
    while((size_t)i < nlen){
        while(j >= 0 && needle[i] != needle[j]){
            j = borders[j];
        }
        ++i;
        ++j;
        borders[i] = j;
    }
    return borders;
}

char *kmp_search(char *haystack, size_t haylen, char *needle, size_t nlen, int *borders){
    size_t max_index = haylen-nlen, i = 0, j = 0;
    while(i <= max_index){
        while(j < nlen && *haystack && needle[j] == *haystack){
            ++j;
            ++haystack;
        }
        if (j == nlen){
            return haystack-nlen;
        }
        if (!(*haystack)){
            return NULL;
        }
        if (j == 0){
            ++haystack;
            ++i;
        } else {
            do{
                i += j - (size_t)borders[j];
                j = borders[j];
            }while(j > 0 && needle[j] != *haystack);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

char *sstrnstr(char *haystack, char *needle, size_t haylen){
    if (!haystack || !needle){
        return NULL;
    }
    size_t nlen = strlen(needle);
    if (haylen < nlen){
        return NULL;
    }
    int *borders = kmp_borders(needle, nlen);
    if (!borders){
        return NULL;
    }
    char *match = kmp_search(haystack, haylen, needle, nlen, borders);
    free(borders);
    return match;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

See if the function below works for you.  I haven't tested it thoroughly, so I would suggest you do so.

```
char *sstrstr(char *haystack, char *needle, size_t length)
{
    size_t needle_length = strlen(needle);
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (i + needle_length > length) {
            return NULL;
        }
        if (strncmp(&haystack[i], needle, needle_length) == 0) {
            return &haystack[i];
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: That's actually similar to what I'm currently using, but it's O(mn), whereas (I'm assuming) `strstr` is O(m + n). So I'm looking for something that's not ridiculously slow like my version. :-) But +1 anyway, since the idea works.

Comment: @Mehrdad:  Might also be worth it to take a peek at this implementation:  http://src.gnu-darwin.org/src/lib/libc/string/strnstr.c.html

Comment: Wow, I guess I was wrong then... so `strstr` is typically defined to be an O(mn) operation?? Thanks for pointing that out... then I'll probably accept this in a bit, since it's the exact substitute for the question.

Comment: @Mehrdad:  I cleaned up my solution a bit, if you would like to take a look at it again.

Comment: @Mehrdad C does not specify/define the O() of `strstr()`.

Comment: You could avoid the per-loop check for `if (i + needle_length > length)` by just reducing `length` appropriately so the `for` loop condition is correct. `if (needle_length > length) return NULL;`, then `length -= needle_length;`, and the `for` loop becomes `for (i = 0; i <= length; i++)` (changing `<` to `<=` to ensure you check the last possible position). The first `if` check is only necessary because you use `size_t`; using `ssize_t` would remove the need for that check. Good compiler might be smart enough to eliminate `if` for you, but why write complex code and hope if you don't need to.

Comment: It would also be possible to optimize an implementation like this by: 1) Using `memcmp` to avoid `NUL` checking of `strncmp`. 2) Using `memchr` to find the first character of the needle in the haystack, so you're not making a `strncmp`/`memcmp` function call for every character (likely reducing the number of calls by a factor of 50x-100x). Or skip memchr and just test the first character manually before calling `strncmp`/`memcmp`.

Answer (score 5):

I just came across this and I'd like to share my implementation. It think it quite fast a I don't have any subcalls.

It returns the index in the haystack where the needle is found or -1 if it was not found.

```
/* binary search in memory */
int memsearch(const char *hay, int haysize, const char *needle, int needlesize) {
    int haypos, needlepos;
    haysize -= needlesize;
    for (haypos = 0; haypos <= haysize; haypos++) {
        for (needlepos = 0; needlepos < needlesize; needlepos++) {
            if (hay[haypos + needlepos] != needle[needlepos]) {
                // Next character in haystack.
                break;
            }
        }
        if (needlepos == needlesize) {
            return haypos;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Should of went ahead and made it Boyer-Moore while you were at it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I used this method

```
int memsearch(char* dataset, int datasetLength, char* target, int targetLen){
    for(int i = 0; i < datasetLength; i++){
            if(dataset[i] == target[0]){
                    int found = 1;
                    for(int j = 0; j < targetLen; j++){
                            int k = i + j;
                            if(k >= datasetLength || target[j] != dataset[k]){
                                    found = 0;
                                    break;
                            }
                    }
                    if(found) return i;
            }
    }
    return -1;
}
```