# Search Binary File for a Pattern

Tags: c, file, binary

I need to search for a binary pattern in binary file,
how can i do it?

I tried with "strstr()" function and convert the file and the pattern to a string but its not working.

(the pattern is also a binary file)
this is what it tried:

```
void isinfected(FILE *file, FILE *sign, char filename[], char filepath[])
{
char* fil,* vir;
int filelen, signlen;
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
fseek(sign, 0, SEEK_END);
filelen = ftell(file);
signlen = ftell(sign);

fil = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * filelen);
if (!fil)
{
    printf("unseccesful malloc!\n");
}

vir = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * signlen);

if (!vir)
{
    printf("unseccesful malloc!\n");
}

fseek(file, 0, SEEK_CUR);
fseek(sign, 0, SEEK_CUR);

fread(fil, 1, filelen, file);
fread(vir, 1, signlen, sign);
if (strstr(vir, fil) != NULL)
    log(filename, "infected",filepath );
else
    log(filename, "not infected", filepath);
free(vir);
free(fil);
}
```

Comment: assuming that the pattern fits in memory, store it as a string, and have also another (FIFO) buffer of the same size, to check if they are equal.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and explain in what way(s) "its not working": what did you expect, and what happens instead?

Comment: Note: "convert the file and the pattern to a string" is *not* what you did with the cast `char *`. Creating a pointer to a `char` does not *by definition* make it a valid C string. This would only work if both your `fil` and `vir` data were valid, zero terminated C strings.

Answer (score 2):

For *any* binary handling you should **never** use one of the `strXX` functions, because these only (and exclusively) work on C-style zero terminated strings. Your code is failing because the `strXX` functions cannot look beyond the first binary 0 they encounter.

As your basic idea with `strstr` appears correct (and *only* fails because it works on zero terminated strings only), you can replace it with [`memmem`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmem.3.html), which does the same on arbitrary data. Since `memmem` is a GNU C extension (see also [Is there a particular reason for memmem being a GNU extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263582/is-there-a-particular-reason-for-memmem-being-a-gnu-extension)), it may not be available on your system and you need to write code that does the same thing.

For a very basic implementation of `memmem` you can use `memchr` to scan for the first binary character, followed by `memcmp` if it found something:

```
void * my_memmem(const void *big, size_t big_len, const void *little, size_t little_len)
{
    void *iterator;
    if (big_len < little_len)
        return NULL;

    iterator = (void *)big;
    while (1)
    {
        iterator = memchr (iterator, ((unsigned char *)little)[0], big_len - (iterator-big));
        if (iterator == NULL)
            return NULL;
        if (iterator && !memcmp (iterator, little, little_len))
            return iterator;
        iterator++;
    }
}
```

There are better implementations possible, but unless `memmem` is an important function in your program, it'll do the job just fine.

Comment: The conclusion the strstr doesn't work because this is a binary file is probably correct.  memmem, however, is a GNU C extension, not a standard library call or a function available in the Windows API.

Comment: you could always find the source code to memmem (hint it is here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.40.1/string/FreeBSD/memmem.c) and add it, with proper attribution, to your project.  You may need to 'tweak' it a bit to get it to compile on Windows, but looking at the code it should not be to difficult

Comment: @thurizas: ... I wrote a test program using `memmem` to verify against, and then created the above function – with a footnote because, boy, this is ugly. There is *definitely* room for improvement. Only after that I checked your link. ... \*ouch\*! Note To Self: If I ever need an efficient `memmem`, write it myself!

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to check if `vir` matches the beginning of `fil`.  If it doesn't, then you check again, starting at the second byte of `fil`, and repeating until you find a match or until you've reached the end of `fil`.  (This is essentially what a simple implementation of `strstr` does, except that `strstr` treats 0 bytes as a special case.)

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < filelen - signlen; ++i) {
  if (memcmp(vir, fil + i, signlen) == 0) {
    return true;   // vir exists in fil found
  }
}
return false;  // vir is not in file
```

This is the "brute force" approach.  It can get very slow if your files are long.  There are advanced searching algorithms that can potentially make this much faster, but this is a good starting point.