# Accurately search for all positions of a string in a large binary file in C

Tags: c, binaryfiles

I'm currently working on a program that will parse a raw h264/MVC video file (which are found in 3D BluRays), and collect the depth values used to give subtitles a 3D effect.

To do this I have to search the file for a string called "OFMD", and then read the bytes that sit after that string.  Since there are a lot of these OFMDs I have to repeat this for all instances within the file.

I was able to write a Python method that does this pretty well.

```
blockSize = 1048576
with open(fileName, 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        keepgoing = True
        piece = f.read(blockSize)
        posOFMD = piece.find(b'OFMD')
        while posOFMD == -1:
            piece += f.read(blockSize)
            posOFMD = piece.find(b'OFMD')
            if os.stat(fileName).st_size == f.tell():
                keepgoing = False
                break
        if not keepgoing:
            break
        # Seek file to pos of OFMD.
        f.seek(-len(piece), 1)
        f.seek(posOFMD, 1)

        piece = f.read(blockSize)

        # Process 'piece'
        # Seek file to the pos of OFMD plus 1.
        f.seek(-len(piece), 1)
        f.seek(1, 1)
```

I'd like to get this function working in C, but the problem I'm running into is that I can't figure out how to stop the loop after reaching the end-of-file while also accurately catching all "OFMD" strings.

Here's a portion of the code I've tried.  The rest can be found on this [Github gist.](https://gist.github.com/TheGreatMcPain/844a694a702a28830528b724e754f55c)

```
  mvcFile = fopen(fileName, "rb");
  fseek(mvcFile, 0L, SEEK_END);
  mvcFileSize = ftell(mvcFile);
  fseek(mvcFile, 0L, SEEK_SET);

  while (1) {
    keepgoing = 1;
    buffer = (char *)malloc(blockSize * sizeof(char));
    fread(buffer, blockSize, 1, mvcFile);
    size_t nbytes = blockSize;

    if ((OFMDptr = my_memmem(buffer, blockSize, "OFMD", 4)) != NULL) {
      posOFMD = OFMDptr - buffer;
    } else {
      posOFMD = -1;
    }
    // Until we find new posOFMD. Search more of the file.
    while (posOFMD == -1) {
      buffer = (char *)realloc(buffer, (blockSize + nbytes) * sizeof(char));
      fread(buffer + nbytes, blockSize, 1, mvcFile);
      nbytes += blockSize;
      if ((OFMDptr = my_memmem(buffer, nbytes, "OFMD", 4)) != NULL) {
        posOFMD = OFMDptr - buffer;
      } else {
        posOFMD = -1;
      }
      // TODO: When we reach the end of the file stop the loops.
      if (feof(mvcFile)) {
        keepgoing = 0;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (keepgoing == 0) {
      break;
    }
    // Seek file to the OFMD's location
    fseek(mvcFile, -(nbytes), SEEK_CUR);
    fseek(mvcFile, posOFMD, SEEK_CUR);
    // Load a chunk of the file starting at the position of the OFMD.
    buffer = (char *)realloc(buffer, blockSize * sizeof(char));
    fread(buffer, blockSize, 1, mvcFile);
    // Process Data.
    // Seek file to the OFMD's location plus 1 byte.
    fseek(mvcFile, -(blockSize), SEEK_CUR);
    fseek(mvcFile, 1, SEEK_CUR);
    free(buffer);
  }
}
```

the `my_memmem` function comes from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30683927/13793328)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can obtain the file size and compare the amount you have read with it. -- Reading in fixed sized blocks can make you ignore an "OFMD" if it is going over a block border. -- I would expect that even such "raw" data is kind of structured in (differently sized) chunks. Also I suspect "OFMD" to be some kind of type information of the chunk of your interest. Why don't you just read each chunk and look at the type information?

Comment: I'm using an inner while loop that appends more of the file if it can't find OFMD on the first chunk.  Also the OFMD does have a structure, but it doesn't have a type like you suggest.  For example the frame-rate value is stored on the first byte after the OFMD string,  the number of frames for the current OFMD is stored on the 7th byte after OFMD, and the actual subtitle 3D depth values start at the 10th byte after OFMD.

Comment: Better to use a memory-mapped file instead. It is suitable for working with a large file.

Comment: If you just brute-force scan the file for some specific 4 character string, how do you prevent false-positive matches? I don't know anything about the file format, but i would guess that those 4 bytes could appear anywhere in the file, for example in one of the audio streams or somewhere in the middle of an image. If you know the details of the file format, it should be possible to traverse it in a smarter way.

Comment: To check for false positives I check if the frame rate value (the first byte after the string "OFMD") is valid since it can only be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, or 7 most of the time it will be 1, because it represents 24fps.  Also, this program will only work with a raw h264/mvc stream, so there shouldn't be any audio along with the video.

Comment: That will reduce the probability of a false positive, but it can still happen. The fact that there is no audio doesn't matter, as it was just meant as an example of "data that isn't actually a subtitle". The point i'm trying to make is that it is not only safer, but also usually much, much faster to follow the structure of a file instead of ignoring it (because you can skip a lot of data that can't possibly be a subtitle anyway)

Comment: I understand that knowing the structure of a h264/MVC would be a great help as it could also help improve the program later like being able to rip the 3D-Planes from a m2ts rather than requiring a demuxed MVC stream.  I'll ask around doom9 to see if anyone could help me with that.  Also, I'm using a method that was used in an older program that was written in pascel which has worked for years.  I don't think I can share the original source code, because the author only gave it to me for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I rewrote my program, and managed to solve my issue.
[Here's a new Github gist with my new program.](https://gist.github.com/TheGreatMcPain/a3d05c2dbb5518417d2477ae0878a443)

I've put my search code in a new function that moves the file pointer to the start of the string if it is found.  Other wise it will return NULL.

To stop it from continuously reading the file all I needed to do was keep track of how much of the file was left. Once the number of bytes left in the file is smaller than my `blockSize` I would just only search for the string inside what's left of the file.

Here's a piece of code from my new function.

```
  fileLeft = fileSize - ftell(file);

  // Initialize buffer.
  buffer = (char *)malloc(blockSize * sizeof(char));
  fread(buffer, 1, blockSize, file);

  // If we're reaching the end of the file.
  // Only search the last chunk of the file.
  if (fileLeft < BlockSize) {
    if ((offsetPtr = my_memmem(buffer, blockSize, small, smallSize)) != NULL) {
      smallPos = offsetPtr - buffer;
      fseek(file, -blockSize, SEEK_CUR);
      fseek(file, smallPos, SEEK_CUR);
      free(buffer);
      return file;
    } else {
      free(buffer);
      return NULL;
    }
  }
```

I still need to improve the function a bit so that it doesn't continuously eat memory if it sits in that while loop for too long searching the string.  Other than that I think I've figured it out.