# Sharing text file between processes with open() and mmap()

Tags: c, fork, ipc, mmap

I'm trying to share a text file between forked processes on my Ubuntu x86_64: the file will not be absurdly large, since strings will be written only if there is not already another identical string in the file; strings will be hostnames of visited websites, so I'll assume no more than 255 bytes for each hostname.

When it is a process' turn to write in shared object, it is OK; once all the processes wrote in shared object, `msync` should make the writing effective on the disk, but the `mapped.txt` file created only contain one string from `arrayString`, i.e. the string the last process wrote in shared object.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <string.h>

// first forked process will write "first" in file, and so on
const char *arrayString[] = {
    "first", 
    "second",
    "third"
};

int main(void) {

    int index;
    int children = 3;
    const char *filepath = "mapped.txt";
    sem_t *sem;

    sem = sem_open("semaphore", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, 1);
    sem_unlink("semaphore");
    int fd;
    fd = open(filepath, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open:");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char *data;
    data = (char *)mmap(NULL, getpagesize(), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (data == MAP_FAILED) {
        close(fd);
        perror("mmap:");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (index=0; index<children; index++) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            sem_wait(sem);

            size_t textsize = strlen(arrayString[index])+1;

            if (ftruncate(fd, sizeof(textsize)) == -1) {
                perror("ftruncate:");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            for (size_t i = 0; i < textsize; i++) {
                printf("%d Writing character %c at %zu\n", getpid(), arrayString[index][i], i);
                data[i] = arrayString[index][i];
            }

            printf("%d wrote ", getpid());
            for (size_t i = 0; i < textsize; i++) {
                printf("%c", data[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");

            if (msync(data, textsize, MS_SYNC) == -1) {
                perror("Could not sync the file to disk");
            }

            sem_post(sem);
            _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }
    close(fd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is one possible output of the code above for three child processes (this is fine):

```
20373 Writing character s at 0
20373 Writing character e at 1
20373 Writing character c at 2
20373 Writing character o at 3
20373 Writing character n at 4
20373 Writing character d at 5
20373 Writing character  at 6
20373 wrote second
20374 Writing character t at 0
20374 Writing character h at 1
20374 Writing character i at 2
20374 Writing character r at 3
20374 Writing character d at 4
20374 Writing character  at 5
20374 wrote third
20372 Writing character f at 0
20372 Writing character i at 1
20372 Writing character r at 2
20372 Writing character s at 3
20372 Writing character t at 4
20372 Writing character  at 5
20372 wrote first
```

And here's the content of `mapped.txt` (this is bad):

```
first^@^@^@
```

I expected:

```
second
third
first
```

but all I get is only the string of the last process, with those strange symbols. I'd like to keep this file persistent in memory, but because of the I/O slowness, I'm trying to use memory mapping.
Any idea why my file only contains the string written by the last process accessing the shared file?

**Edit**: I think I get it, it seems to work now: I hope it will be of help to someone. Compiled with `g++ -g -o mapthis mapthis.cpp -lrt -pthread`. Beware that some error checking are missing, like for `fsync`, `snprintf` and `lseek`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

const char *arrayString[] = {
    "www.facebook.com",
    "www.google.com",
    "www.cnn.com",
    "www.speechrepository.com",
    "www.youtube.com",
    "www.facebook.com",
    "www.google.com",
    "www.cnn.com",
    "www.speechrepository.com",
    "www.youtube.com",
    "www.facebook.com",
    "www.google.com",
    "www.cnn.com",
    "www.speechrepository.com",
    "www.youtube.com"
};

int main(void) {

    int index;
    int children = sizeof(arrayString) / sizeof(char*);;
    const char *filepath = "mapped.txt";
    sem_t *sem;
    char *data;
    struct stat filestats;

    sem = sem_open("semaphore", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, 1);
    sem_unlink("semaphore");
    int fd;
    fd = open(filepath, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open:");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (fstat(fd, &filestats) < 0) {
        close(fd);
        perror("fstat:");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    data = (char *)mmap(NULL, filestats.st_size ? filestats.st_size : 1, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (data == MAP_FAILED) {
        close(fd);
        perror("first map:");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (index=0; index<children; index++) {
        sleep(1);
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {
            int nw = 0;
            int hostnameSize = 0;
            const size_t origsize = filestats.st_size;
            char *hostPos = NULL;
            char *numPos = NULL;
            char *backslashPos = NULL;
            char tempBuff[64];
            memset((char *)tempBuff, 0, sizeof(tempBuff));
            sem_wait(sem);
            // remap to current file size if it changed
            fstat(fd, &filestats);
            // file empty, just insert
            if (filestats.st_size == 0) {
                nw = snprintf(tempBuff, sizeof(tempBuff), "%s %010lu\n", arrayString[index], (unsigned long)time(NULL));
                write(fd, tempBuff, nw);
                fsync(fd);
            }
            else {
                // file not empty, let's look for string
                hostPos = strstr(data, arrayString[index]);
                if (hostPos) {
                    // string is already inserted, search for offset of number of seconds
                    lseek(fd, hostPos-data, SEEK_SET);
                    numPos = strchr(hostPos, ' ')+1;
                    backslashPos = strchr(numPos, '\n');
                    long unsigned before = atoi(numPos);
                    long unsigned now = (unsigned long)time(NULL);
                    long unsigned difference = now - before;
                    printf("%s visited %ld seconds ago (%ld - %ld)\n", 
                        arrayString[index], difference, now, before);
                    nw = snprintf(tempBuff, backslashPos-hostPos+1, "%s %010lu", arrayString[index], now);
                    write(fd, tempBuff, nw);
                    write(fd, "\n", 1);
                    fsync(fd);
                }
                else {
                    data = (char *)mremap(data, origsize, filestats.st_size, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);
                    if (data == MAP_FAILED) {
                        close(fd);
                        sem_post(sem);
                        perror("mmap:");
                        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
                    nw = snprintf(tempBuff, sizeof(tempBuff), "%s %010lu\n", arrayString[index], (unsigned long)time(NULL));
                    write(fd, tempBuff, nw);
                    fsync(fd);
                }
            }
            munmap(data, filestats.st_size);
            close(fd);
            sem_post(sem);
            _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        else if (pid > 0) {
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
    munmap(data, filestats.st_size);
    close(fd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is problematic:

```
if (ftruncate(fd, sizeof(textsize)) == -1) {
```

`textsize` is a `size_t`, and taking its `sizeof` is just going to get 4 or 8 (on 32 and 64 bit systems). Looks like you're on a 64 bit system, so you're unconditionally truncating the file to 8 bytes in this case before every write. The "strange symbols" are just how your editor displays `NUL`/zero bytes. Even if you used `ftruncate(fd, textsize)`, you'd still truncate down to just the string you're about to write, overwriting any data other children may have written; I doubt you want to `ftruncate` at all here.

For continual appends from separate processes (where they can't share information about the size or offset of the data they're adding), memory mapping just doesn't make sense; why aren't you just having each of them take the lock, `lseek` to end of file, then call `write`? You could still use memory mappings for the duplicate checking (some of it without locking), it would just be a bit different. Something like this:

```
int main(void) {
    struct stat filestats;
    int index;
    int children = 3;
    const char *filepath = "mapped.txt";
    sem_t *sem;
    char *data;

    sem = sem_open("semaphore", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, 1);
    sem_unlink("semaphore");
    int fd;
    fd = open(filepath, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open:");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Mostly just to ensure it's mappable, we map the current size of the file
    // If the file might already have values, and many child workers won't add
    // to it, this might save some mapping work in the children; you could
    // just map in the children when needed though
    if (fstat(fd, &filestats) != 0) {
        close(fd);
        perror("fstat:");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    data = mmap(NULL, filestats.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (data == MAP_FAILED) {
        close(fd);
        perror("mmap:");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (index=0; index<children; index++) {
        if (fork() == 0) {
            const size_t origsize = filestats.st_size;
            sem_wait(sem);

            // remap to current file size if it changed
            // If you're not on Linux, you'd just have to mmap from scratch
            // since mremap isn't standard
            fstat(fd, &filestats);
            if (origsize != filestats.st_size) {
                data = mremap(data, origsize, filestats.st_size, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);
                if (data == MAP_FAILED) {
                    close(fd);
                    sem_post(sem);
                    perror("mmap:");
                    _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }

            // Not safe to use strstr since mapping might not end with NUL byte
            // You'd need to workaround this, or implement a your own memstr-like function
            if (!memstr(data, arrayString[index])) {
                // Move fd to end of file, so we append new data
                lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
                write(fd, arrayString[index], strlen(arrayString[index]));
                write(fd, "\n", 1);
                fsync(fd);
            }
            munmap(data, filestats.st_size);
            close(fd);
            sem_post(sem);
            _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }
    munmap(data, filestats.st_size);
    close(fd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

That `memstr` I referenced would need to be hand-implemented (or you'd need to do terrible things like ensure the file always had a `NUL` byte at the end so you could use `strstr` on it); you can get some tips on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8584644/364696).

Comment: Your answer surely deserves a test, let me try it on my code.

Comment: Turned out your answer is the best: your call to `mmap` had `invalid argument` because I passed it `0` as `size_t length`, so first time I passed it `getpagesize()`; I used `snprint` to write in a temporary buffer and then `write` in `data` the number of bytes  written in this buffer; now I can see if a string was already inserted in shared file. Still having difficulties in updating string: the real structure is `hostname time_t` and even if I can get `time_t` seconds, I need to write the new `time_t` seconds of the last visit, but that is another matter.

Comment: @elmazzun: Ah, yeah, forgot about length `0` being verboten on some OSes; you could just as easily use a length of `filestats.st_size ? filestats.st_size : 1` (which will map a whole page anyway, since that's how `mmap` operates, and avoids needing to check the real page size).

Comment: Just one more thing: every row in my file is `string int`; if `string` is already inserted take `int`, compute the difference between `time_t now = time(NULL)` and `int` field, update the difference inserting `time_t now` in `int` field for future visits and differences; when I write the new `time_t` value in `int` field, do I need to `mremap` again just for updating the `int` field?

Comment: @elmazzun: Depends how it's stored. If it's a string timestamp padded to a fixed width, or a raw binary timestamp, then no remapping would be required; the size never changes. I'd strongly recommend one of those, because the alternative (non-fixed width timestamps) would require annoying and error prone work any time the length of the timestamp changes, to move all of the data following it appropriately.

Comment: My fields are `string ; long unsigned int`, because of the cast I made `(unsigned long)time(NULL)`. For example, a row may be `www.google.com 1472755105`: is this one of the two alternatives you are talking about?

Comment: @elmazzun: You'd need to make sure it was printed with a format code like `%010ld` if times might fall into spans before early Sept. 2001, but not after mid-November 2286 (and yes, times before Sept. 2001 should be handled properly; sometimes computer clocks go awry, and you don't want to corrupt the file if that happens). If you want to handle beyond 2286, use `%011ld`.

Comment: I'd like to share my code, if anyone in future will have my problem. I just hope it is correct, but it seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

You're writing all the strings at offset 0 of the file, each over the top of the previous.  The core of your loop should be something like

```
struct stat status;
fstat(fd, &status);
size_t cursize = status.st_size;
ftruncate(fd, cursize + textsize);
for (size_t i = 0; i < textsize; i++) {
    data[cursize + i] = arrayString[index][i];
}
```

Comment: This loop will write `first^@second^@third^@` in shared file; if I add `\n` at each string in `arrayString`, and calculate `size_t textsize` without `+1`, the file will be perfectly formatted, one string each row; string formatting is important to me, since I'll need to parse strings in this file.

Comment: @elmazzun: As implemented, the mapping won't be large enough if your file ever exceeds the page size (the amount you `mmap`ed). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39254749/364696) for handling this (it means using `mremap` if on Linux, or just deferring the `mmap` step until the child holds the semaphore on other OSes).